# Programmatically uninstall J2ME Application

Tags: java-me, midp

I developed a j2me application. I want this application to uninstall itself at some point after deploying this in a phone. Uninstallation is done without any user's interaction for that. How can do this?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove application from the phone at that time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way for a J2ME app to programatically uninstall itself!  Perhaps display a message asking the user to uninstall it manually?

You can certainly add some logic to make the app effectively useless after a certain event has happened...  so when the user starts it up they just get a screen saying "please uninstall me", with no other functionality.